# Time tracking app arbtt case insensitive match in rules

Tags: arbtt

is it possible to use modifiers on regex? Like:

`m/some.*title/i ==> tag...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `arbtt` uses perl-compatible regexes, and they allow you to set modifiers inside the pattern:

```
m/(?i)some.*title/ ==> tag...
```

See https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC13 for more details.